# Use Python to click href of type javascript:void(0) to retrieve tar file

Tags: javascript, python, href, tar

I am looking to retrieve a suite of tar files from a website via python.
Generally, the links are of the form:

```
< td > < a > href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="dlResp('tar','SHR')" >Click Here< /a >/< td >
```

I believe that it is the javascript:void(0) that is giving trouble. I have not been successful in retrieving the tar files using `browser.mechanise()` or selenium PhantomJS. Can anybody help?

This must run as a background process so a web driver such as firefox or chrome is not acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: can you fix the html please? there's unneded spaces, and the a tag is closed before the href

Comment: also: do you `need` to parse the site first, can't you see what the site does in your browser and fetch the resulting url directly?

Comment: add url to this page - maybe we can find links in HTML and you will don't have to work with JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, added spaces as the a, td etc disappeared without them (as you'd expect on a web page?)

Comment: <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="dlResp('tar','YSI')">Click Here</a></td>

Comment: Url: http://www.fnet.bosai.go.jp/st_info/response.php?LANG=en

Comment: www.fnet.bosai.go.jp/st_info/response.php?LANG=en

Answer (score 0):

The link executes `dlResp('tar', 'SHR')` when being clicked.

If we look at the javascript of the page you linked, we find the function definition:

```
function dlResp(resp,code){
   var url = './dlTxt.php?resp=' + resp + '&code=' + code;
   location.href = url;
}
```

Which means you can download the tar files from URLs like the following: `http://www.fnet.bosai.go.jp/st_info/dlTxt.php?resp=tar&code=SHR`

So you need to parse the onClick attribute and retrieve this URL:

```
# Put the contents of the onClick attribute here
onclick = "dlResp('tar', 'SHR')"
url_template = "http://www.fnet.bosai.go.jp/st_info/dlTxt.php?resp={1}&code={3}"
url = url_template.format(*onclick.split("'"))
# Retrieve `url` using whatever library
```