# How do I extract link from website if after parsing in Python, the download link is not extracted. And also the href attribute is javascript:void(0)

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to code a sort of YouTube downloader that takes a YouTube video url, uses requests and BeautifulSoup to scrape the download link of that video from an online video downloader.

**Website used** - https://www.y2mate.com/

**Approach:** nifty feature of above website that allows the following:
Use `https://www.youtubepp.com/` followed by the video link, say `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ`.
Doing so takes you to the website, with the YouTube video already entered in the search bar.
This thus allows using this kind of special link in the `requests` module to extract the required links.

**Issues:**

1. Inspecting the download link shows href like so (for 480p
   download):
   `<a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="nofollow" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#progress" data-ftype="mp4" data-fquality="480"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i>&nbsp; Download </a>`

   How do I extract the link from this `href="javascript:void(0)`?
   I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771745/use-python-to-click-href-of-type-javascriptvoid0-to-retrieve-tar-file)
   SO question but it doesnt help me because I cant find the onClick attribute
2. Apart from this issue, i ran the following code to extract the html of the page:

   ```py
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import requests

   DOMAIN = "https://www.youtubepp.com/"
   URL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"

   download_url = DOMAIN + URL

   params = {
     "hl": "en"    # I needed this because by default I was not getting English
   }

   res = requests.get(download_url, params=params)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

   print(soup.prettify())
   ```

On inspecting the output, I find that the part which has the links I need is not even displayed.
How do I then succesfully extract the download link if it does not even come after parsing with beautifulsoup.

**Alternate attempt:**

Due to the first issue, I tried using a different website from which to extract the download link.
In this website, we can use `https://www.ssyoutube.com/` followed by the `watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ` part of the video link(http://youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

This does solve the first issue, but the second issue is also found by using this website

---

**EDIT 3** (After @Lima's response)

I tried the without regex approach but it gives the same error, the reason was apparent by your debug messages

```
Jim Yosef - Link [NCS Release]
DEBUG:
DEBUG:  (<- need to bee the value of var k__id)
1: {'quality': '1080p HFR', 'type': 'mp4'}
2: {'quality': '720p HFR', 'type': 'mp4'}
3: {'quality': '480', 'type': 'mp4'}
4: {'quality': '360', 'type': 'mp4'}
5: {'quality': '240p', 'type': 'mp4'}
6: {'quality': '144p', 'type': 'mp4'}
7: {'quality': '144p', 'type': '3gp'}
8: {'quality': '128', 'type': 'mp3'}
9: {'quality': '128', 'type': 'mp3'}
Select stream [1-9]: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\rayya\Other\Web_Scraping\Youtube Download\sol2.py", line 71, in <module>
    toDownload = download.attrs["href"]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

So for some reason the `.getText()` method returns `None` (I believe it return None cuz of that output). Which tells me it was the same problem last time, `.getText()` would return `None` and then `regex` would not find any matches.

However, because you said we're looking for the `var k_id` value. I tried using my 'fix' to get the `<script>` tag and then used regex on that to get the value of `var k_id`.

```
myScript = soup.findAll("script", {"type": "text/javascript"})[0]   # instead of using the .find().getText() method
print("DEBUG:", myScript)    # this worked, I skipped it in the output cuz of clutter

getId = re.compile(r'(?<=var k__id = ")\w*(?=";)')
tmpID = getId.findall(myScript)[0]
print("DEBUG:", tmpID, "(<- need to bee the value of var k__id)")
```

Unfortunately gave the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\rayya\Other\Web_Scraping\Youtube Download\main.py", line 62, in <module>
    tmpID = getId.findall(myScript)[0]
  File "C:\Users\rayya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\re.py", line 241, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

**BUT BUT BUT...**
I printed `type(myScript)` and got `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`
All I had to do now was `myScript = str(myScript)` and then everything worked like a charm. It was like music to my ears, but to my eyes. (Dont ask :) lol)

---

**EDIT** (After attempting @Lima 's solution)

I am getting the following error (I used the video id that you commented:

```
Youtube video id: 9iHM6X6uUH8
Jim Yosef - Link [NCS Release]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\rayya\Other\Web_Scraping\Youtube Download\main.py", line 58, in <module>
    tmpID = re.findall(getId, soup.find("script", {"type": "text/javascript"}).getText())[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**EDIT 2** (examining the error)

I noticed that in the line `tmpID = re.findall(getId, soup.find("script",("type": "text/javascript"}).getText())[0]` we are looking for something to do with `"script"` and `"type text/javascript"`

So after the declaration of `soup`, I printed `soup.prettify()`. [Here](https://pastebin.com/THcs98ni) is the output of that and you notice in line 273 is the thing we are looking for, but it was not being found for some reason

I tried changing the line to `tmpID = soup.findAll("script", {"type": "text/javascript"})[0]` by pretty much copying the syntax of the `links` variable declaration just below. **And it worked**

**BUT...**
It now gives a whole new error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\rayya\Other\Web_Scraping\Youtube Download\main.py", line 91, in <module>
    toDownload = download.attrs["href"]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

So again, I printed `soup.prettify()` but this time after the second declaration of `soup`. [This](https://pastebin.com/KP3D5q5F) is the output. And I have no idea how to proceed any further

Comment: I can recommend [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp), or [pytube](https://github.com/pytube/pytube) to download YouTube videos

Comment: @Lima I previously already made one with pytube. I am making this one for two reasons, a) the one with pytube now gives me an import error even though i hav it installed, b) i wanted to get better at webscraping. I would check out yt-dlp though. Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: I avoided regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import parse
import requests, json#, re

Id = parse.quote(input("Youtube video id: ")) # Like: 9iHM6X6uUH8

res = requests.post("https://www.y2mate.com/mates/en115/analyze/ajax",
                  headers={
                      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                      "Alt-Used": "www.y2mate.com",
                      "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
                      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
                      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin"
                      },
                  data="url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D{}&q_auto=0&ajax=1".format(Id)
                  )
data = json.loads(res.content)
if not data['status'] == 'success':
    raise RuntimeError(f"data['status'] == {data['status']}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(data['result'], "html.parser")
if not soup.findChild().attrs['class'] == ['tabs', 'row']:
    raise FileNotFoundError("Video does not exist")
name = soup.find('div', {'class': ['caption', 'text-left']}).findChild('b').getText()
print(name)
myScript = soup.find('script', {'type':'text/javascript'}).getText()
print('DEBUG:', myScript)
#getId = re.compile(r'(?<=var k__id = ")\w*(?=";)')
tmpID = myScript[70+len(name):70+24+len(name)] #re.findall(getId, myScript)[0]
print('DEBUG:', tmpID, '(<- need to bee the value of var k__id)')
links = soup.findAll('a', {'class': ["btn", "btn-success"]})
streams = []
for i, link in enumerate(links):
    stream = {
        'quality': link.attrs['data-fquality'],
        'type': link.attrs['data-ftype']
        }
    streams.append(stream)
    print(f'{i+1}: {stream}')

myStream = streams[int(input(f"Select stream [1-{len(streams)}]: "))-1]

res = requests.post("https://www.y2mate.com/mates/convert",
                    headers={
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                        "Alt-Used": "www.y2mate.com",
                        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
                        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
                        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin"
                        },
                    data="type=youtube&_id={verify}&v_id={vid}&ajax=1&token=&ftype={type}&fquality={quality}" \
                        .format(**myStream, verify=tmpID, vid=Id)
                    )

data = json.loads(res.content)
if not data['status'] == 'success':
    raise RuntimeError(f"data['status'] == {data['status']}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(data['result'], "html.parser")
download = soup.find('a', {'class': ['btn', 'btn-success', 'btn-file']})
toDownload = download.attrs['href']

print('Here is the download link:')
print(toDownload)
```

I finded out this with chrome devtools:

- I opened the network tab
- Pasted a yt url
- Clicked a download button
- And I saw 2 POST requests (to what url, with headers, date, and respons)

Comment: Ok first of all, Thanks a ton for the effort, I really do appreciate it. Now, I am getting an error, check my edit

Comment: So I did some tinkering, and though I dont know much about this I was able to make some progress. Please check my edit

Comment: _in line 273 is the thing we are looking for_: yes, but i want to extract from script the variable `var k__id = "6135a4f9f99cc55e408b45c7";`. I need to send back this value to can download: `.format(**myStream, verify=tmpID, vid=Id)`. I used a regex `(?<=var k__id = ")\w*(?=";)` to extract everything between `var k__id = "` and `";`. this _tmpID = soup.findAll("script", {"type": "text/javascript"})[0]_ fix isn't good, because we need to send back only the `k__id`'s value. The anther error after fix was, the server responded with an error message, and the soup dodn't find any <a>.

Comment: Oh I see, that would make sense. Im curious tho, shouldnt `data["status"] == "success"` return `False` because server responds with an error message?

Comment: The server returns a success to the site to render the error html message. I think the server will return something else, if gets an error server side.

Comment: It didnt work but... Check my Edit 3. Thank you so very much for the help, I definitely learned a lot. If you dont mind, I wanted to know how you got knew what `url`, `headers` and `data` should be passed in `requests.post()`. And could you tell me a regex to extract the videoId from the url of the video? I tried but cant find a way to exclude things after the Id (if any). Lastly, do you know any sources I can learn more about this stuff? PS. you dont have to answer all my questions but it would be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you make the required changes to your answer so then I can accept it